# Add Color to Positive and Negative Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to create a graph to represent projected vs collected revenue by person and I'm not sure how to do this. The goal would be to have the negative differences plotted as a red vertical bar and positive as black.

```
ggplot(appts2, 
       aes(Provider, Difference), 
       main = "Difference in Projected vs Actual Revenue") + 
  geom_bar(fill = ifelse(appts2$Difference < 0, "red", "black"), stat = 'identity') + 
  coord_flip()
```

works but isn't coloring things correctly.

[image]

```
  Provider  Revenue Visits  Ave Total Add Ons   Total Scheduled Total Seen  Total Not Seen  TotalBatchVisits    ProjectedRevenue    Difference  MissingRecords
Smith   40911   539 75.9    38  438 404 82  486 36887.4 -4023.6 53
Antonio 4827    63  76.62   7   88  60  35  95  7278.9  2451.9  -32
Jackson 13832   171 80.89   32  155 161 20  181 14641.09    809.09  -10
Redding 23030   278 82.84   25  164 144 34  178 14745.52    -8284.48    100
```

Comment: Side note: putting `main = "title"` inside `ggplot()` will not give you a plot title, if that's what you intended. You can use `+ ggtitle("title")` or `+ labs(title = "title")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting the "fill" aesthetic to a logical statement, such as `Difference < 0`. **ggplot** will then fill the bars depending on whether the bar is less than or greater than zero.

Never use the `$` operator inside of `aes()` (you reference `appts2$Difference`). Instead, use the bare column name, which **ggplot** will then search for in the provided data set. **ggplot** orders the data before plotting it, so providing an outside vector with `$` can cause strange conflicts with its intended order.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(category = letters[1:10], difference = rnorm(10))

g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = difference, x = category, fill = difference < 0)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
print(g)
```

[image]